# Is fucus filamentous or colonial algea?

Tags: plant-anatomy

Am a bit new to biology SE. My question is wether fucus is filamentous or collonial form of algea?Does a form of algea have to be collonial or fillamentous or it can be something else?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucus_vesiculosus

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking up some [basic sources on types of algae](https://www.algae.info/Algaecomplete.aspx). For example, that source that I link to says this:

> Algae vary considerably in size, shape, and growth form.
> They can be:
>
> - Single celled
> - Many celled - either colonially or as filaments of cells; or
> - Elaborate plant bodies with differentiated cell types

In this case, I believe that *Fucus* would be in the third category ("elaborate plant bodies").

But note that these are informal categories, they don't really correspond to taxonomy or evolution or anything.